# Using guards for different access levels in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4, guard

I have users with different access Levels. I have a general guard that checks that a token is set and allows access if so. However I am confused as how to restrict users entering pages on their access level.
Have done some research but cant see much for ionic 4.

**login.ts**

```js
login(emailin, pwin) {
  const data = {
    email: emailin,
    pw: pwin,
  };

  return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl + 'login.php', JSON.stringify(data))
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe((result) => {
      this.storage.set('token', result.jwt);

      if (result.level === 'Consultant') {
        this.router.navigate(['/menu/first/tabs/tab1'], result);
        this.authState.next(true);
      } else if (result.level === 'Volunteer') {
        this.router.navigate(['register'], result);
        this.authState.next(true);
      } else if (result.level === 'Clinician') {
        this.router.navigate(['/menu/first/tabs/tab1']);
        this.authState.next(true);
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      if (emailin === '' || pwin === '' ) {
        this.alertService.presentAlertLogin();
      } else  if (error.status === 403) {
        this.alertService.presentAlertLogin();
      } else if (error.status === 401) {}
    });
}

isAuthenticated() {
  return this.authState.value;
}
```

**guard.ts**

```js
export class Guard implements CanActivate {
  path: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[];
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

  constructor(public router: Router, public authService: AuthService) { }

  // Works but ony if a JWT is present.
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated() === false) {
      this.router.navigate(['not-found']);
    }
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple guards for the pages that require special access level.
For example,

**Consultant** page will have two guards like below,

```
path : 'consult'
canActivate : [ Guard, ConsultGuard ]
```

For **Clinician**

```
path : 'clincian'
canActivate : [ Guard, ClinicianGuard ]
```

And in those specific guards, you will only check the access level as in order to enter the path, all the guards need to return `true`.

So you will have to save your `login.php` response or just the access level in auth service for the guards to use it.

Comment: But in the new guard how do i check the access level?

Comment: You store it in your auth service. Right when you are storing the token